# MySQL INNER JOIN with different column names

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, inner-join

Okay, so I have two tables, a `news` table and a `users` table. They are set up as below:

news:

```
id title user_id contents
```

users:

```
id username password
```

When I run this query:

```
SELECT news.title, users.username, news.contents FROM news INNER JOIN users ON news.user_id=users.id  WHERE news.id=:id
```

I can only access the user id using `$query['id']`. So it appears that the join is using the column names from table2, although I want them to map it to the column names of table1. So even though the column is called `id` in the users table, I want to access it under `user_id`, since I specified that in the `JOIN` query.

I need this because if I ever need the `id` from table1, they would both be mapped to the column called `id` and I would only be able to get the `id` of the users table.

So is there any way to do this? Access the column from table2 under the name of the column in table1?

Comment: `SELECT table2.whatever AS name_you_want`?

Comment: @Marc B So that would mean I need to use this, right?:
`SELECT news.title, users.id AS user_id, users.username,  news.contents FROM news INNER JOIN users ON news.user_id=users.id  WHERE news.id=:id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL what you specify in the select statement is what it is called in the result set, so you need to tell it what to give you. you do that with the [AS command](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp)

```
SELECT users.id AS user_id ... FROM ...
```

That way you can call it whatever you want

or grab the user_id from news with

```
SELECT news.user_id ... FROM ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT users.id AS id1, news.id AS id2, news.title, users.username, news.contents 
FROM news INNER JOIN users ON news.user_id=users.id  WHERE news.id=:id

echo $query['id1'] . $query['id2'];
```